# How to call text files as user-data in Terraform without UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, user-data

Terraform version: v1.0.4

I am experimenting with user_data attribute for EC2 instances.
Here are the contents of a .txt file that I am trying to use at the moment,

```
#cloud-config
aws_image: true
```

Following are the scenarios that I have tested

1. Using 'locals'. Works fine.
2. Converting file to UTF-8 encoding and then making use of templates, Works fine.
3. Using a .txt file without UTF-8 encoding, this is the problematic scenario, user-data section for defined EC2 instance turns up empty. I have tested few permutations,

3.1.

```
data "template_file" "user_data_test"{
  template = filebase64("/Users/home/Desktop/centos_ec2_aws/test-user-data.txt")
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_aws_Linux_vm" {
  .
  .
  user_data_base64 = data.template_file.user_data_test.template
}
```

3.2.

```
data "template_file" "user_data_test{
  template = filebase64("/Users/home/Desktop/centos_ec2_aws/test-user-data.txt")
}
resource "aws_instance" "my_aws_Linux_vm" {
  .
  .
  user_data = data.template_file.user_data_test.template
}
```

I am looking for an approach where even if I don't use a .txt or .sh file with UTF-8, my deployment completes without any error. Let me know if this is doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because template files are written in the Terraform language's template syntax, the template itself must always be UTF-8 encoded in order to be valid syntax, but you can in principle write a template that contains expressions which will produce base64 data and then assign that result to `user_data_base64`. With that said, I'm having trouble imagining what a use-case would be for that and you didn't share one so I can't give a real example.

If your intended result is still *text* but using some other character encoding than UTF-8 then an alternative approach would be to have the template and the template result both be UTF-8 but then to convert the resulting string to some other character encoding afterwards.

Here's an example where I've also replaced your use of the deprecated `data "template_file"` with the modern [`templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html):

```
locals {
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/test-user-data.txt", {})
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_aws_Linux_vm" {
  # ...

  user_data_base64 = textencodebase64(local.user_data, "UTF-16LE")
}
```

The above uses [`textencodebase64`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/textencodebase64.html) to translate from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE encoding.

Alternatively, if your goal is just to send a file verbatim to EC2 without Terraform doing any template processing on it at all, you can use `filebase64` directly in the `user_data_base64` argument:

```
  user_data_base64 = filebase64("${path.module}/test-user-data.txt")
```

Comment: I am actually asking about the situations where the file referenced as user-data[inside template or directly fed into user_data] may not be UTF-8 encoded. This is quite possible in environments where UTF-8 is not a default encoding. I stumbled upon this issue when I created a text file on my Windows machine, whereby file wasn't UTF-8 encoded. I didn't see this issue on my Mac or other Linux Machines. But, as pointed out by you and as I see from other resources too, templates and files are expected in UTF-8. Thanks.